# How to pass file from url as variable in a function?

Tags: php

I am trying to set a variable to the .jpg file thats comes from an url.

```
$picture = file_get_contents($picturedirectory);
```

where `$picturedirectory = "http://localhost:8080/Users/101/arows.jpg"`

I get an error that says file does not exist when I try to send it. I should mention that I am using XAMPP. Any ideas how to fix this problem?

UPDATE:

I have more clues:

the is_file($picture) is returning NULL

Comment: If its local then access it locally via a relative or absolute path. When you go live your need to change all your code.

Comment: C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\Users\\101\\arows.jpg I tried this but it still did not work.

Comment: Then `file_get_contents('./Users/101/arows.jpg')` would work.

Comment: It does not work either.

Comment: No it is arows.

Comment: What happens when you try to `echo '<img src="http://localhost:8080/Users/101/arows.jpg">`

Comment: if `$_FILES['name']['tmp-name']` is works then what you want ?

Comment: this php file is not posted to a different is.

Comment: @Tom it works and shows the image.

Comment: `is_file` will not work on URLs. Also make sure you have the [`allow_url_fopen`](http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen) option enabled

Comment: I just checked.

Comment: What is the URL of your `.php` file? Also, it is literally **impossible** for `is_file($picture)` to return `null`. Also, if your code works, `$picture` will be a string representing the binary content of your image file. This is **not** something you would use in `is_file()`

Comment: @Phil http://localhost:8080/36.php

Comment: @joseph.w then, assuming the image file actually exists, all you should need is `$picture = file_get_contents(__DIR__ . '/Users/101/arows.jpg');`. As pointed out above, this will be the **binary contents** of your file in string format. What are you doing with `$picture` next?

Comment: @Phil sending it to different server via api as jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think your url is wrong, you need to pass full url in your $picturedirectory.

```
$picturedirectory = "http://localhost:8080/Users/101/arows.jpg"
```

Comment: Maybe the Port is needet?!

`$picturedirectory = "http://localhost:8080/Users/101/arows.jpg"`

Comment: If the server is running on port 8080, it will not work without port.